# Rendering latest content with custom template in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I have a piece of content that is structured like this:

- Body
- Common
- Containable
- Route

And it also contains an **Image Field**

What I'm trying to do is display a summary on my landingpage containing only the Url and the Image Field Url (url the uploaded image), something like this.

```
<a href="@Model.Path"><img src="@Model.Image.FileName" /></a>
```

Obviously, I'm new to Orchard, and from reading other similar questions around the web I understand that perhaps I should be looking at the `Placement.info` file, however I'm unable to figure out how to use that in order to achieve what I need (which is an image wrapped in an anchortag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that by creating a file called Content-TheNameOfYourType.Summary.cshtml in the views folder of your theme.

Comment: The problem is that when I do create such a file (using ShapeTracing) i get Model.Title, .Header .Content etc. where Model.Content seems to hold all the good stuff. What I'd like to do is be able to write something like @Model.Content.MyImage.FileName...

Comment: The interesting stuff is not in Model.Content (which is a zone), it's in Model.ContentItem. See http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/07/31/so-you-don-t-want-to-use-placement-info.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I had actually read that blogpost earlier without realizing the significance. Now I'm back on track!